# Can I write an SQL query to filter duplicate entries of a combination of columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have found answers regarding searching for duplicates of an entry in one column, but I want to search for duplicates of a combination of entries of two columns.

I have the columns 'Area', 'Status', and 'Update Date' as parts of my table. There are 3 different areas and 2 statuses, but there are duplicates among combinations. By that, I mean that (area1,status1) could have been updated at times t1, t2, and t3. I want to find the earliest instance (first entry in the Update Date column) FOR EACH (area,status) combination for a total of 6 rows in my output. Is this possible?

For example, for this one _id, I need 6 rows. The code below outputs a table of 12 rows for the given _id because there are (area,status) duplicates:

```
select _id, area, status, update_date from history
where area in ('a', 'b', 'c')
        and status in ('done','pending') and request_id = 123
order by update_date desc
```

EDIT: Sorry. I know this is confusing. I'll write it out the long way to hopefully clear things up. For _id1, I need the most up-to-date (a1,s1), (a1,s2), (a2,s1), (a2,s2), (a3,s1), and (a3,s2). Then I need those for _id2, then _id3, and so on.

Hope that makes sense and helps a bit more.

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `MIN` are your friends.

Comment: Your original question says " I want to find the earliest instance (first entry in the Update Date column) FOR EACH (area,status) combination for a total of 6 rows in my output", but then your edit says "I want the most updated one". So which one is it?

Comment: Sorry. I know this is confusing. I'll write it out the long way to hopefully clear things up. For _id1, I need the most up-to-date (a1,s1), (a1,s2), (a2,s1), (a2,s2), (a3,s1), and (a3,s2). Then I need those for _id2, then _id3, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `rank` window function to assign a rank per unique combination of `area` and `status`, and then take the first (=earliest) one for each:

```
SELECT   _id, area, status, update_date 
FROM     (SELECT _id, area, status, update_date,
                 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY area, status
                              ORDER BY update_date ASC) AS rk
          FROM   history
          WHERE  area IN ('a', 'b', 'c') AND
                 status IN ('done', 'pending') AND
                 request_id = 123) t
WHERE    rk = 1
ORDER BY update_date DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a subselect for this, as example.

```
SELECT DISTINCT update_dat._id, h.area, h.status, update_dat.update_date
FROM history h
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 _id, update_date 
    FROM history m
    WHERE m.area = h.area AND m.status = h.status
    ORDER BY update_date
) as update_dat
WHERE h.area in ('a', 'b', 'c')
        and h.status in ('done','pending') and request_id = 123
```

Comment: This won't return the `_id` column OP asked for.

Comment: Yes your right. Overseen the _id. Changed it. Now it should work.

Comment: Yes Mureiniks solution using the `RANK` will be faster. :-) Not much but 12% faster. :-) You should use those solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try Grouping your results:

```
SELECT _id, area, status, update_date FROM history
WHERE area IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
        and status IN ('done','pending') and request_id = 123
GROUP BY status, area
ORDER BY update_date desc
```